# Quantum entanglement as topological entanglement

Tags: entanglement, topological-quantum-computing

According with [Aravind](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-94-017-2732-7_4):

- the Hopf link, [L2a1](http://katlas.org/wiki/L2a1), corresponds to the Bell state $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\big (|00\rangle+|11\rangle\big )$,
- the Borromean link ([L6a4](http://katlas.org/wiki/L6a4)) can be considered as GHZ state $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\big(|000\rangle+|111\rangle\big )$, and
- the link [L6n1](http://katlas.org/wiki/L6n1) can be associated with a W state $W=\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}\big(|001\rangle+|010\rangle+100\rangle\big )$.

But, according [Melnikov *et. al*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.04574), we have a different picture: the Borromean link L6a4 is associated with the W state while L6n1 is associated with the GHZ state.

---

The Hopf Link, or the Bell state:

[image: Hopf Link]

L6a4, or the GHZ state in Aravind and the W state in Melnikov *et al*.:

[image: L6a4]

L6n1, or the W state in Aravind and the GHZ state in Melnikov *et al*.:

[image: L6n1]

---

I am confused with such different assignments. Could someone clarify the issue?

Comment: Probably a link to the first paper is missing, please add it.